# An equivalent of APK Editor Studio for AAB

Tags: android

Hello fellow developers,
Now I have an app in Play Store that I developed with Kodular last year, since the app had so many files in the assets folder it was not possible to compile directly from Kodular so I could export the APK with less than 10 assets and then use APK Editor Studio to add the remaining contents into the app, sign and recompile the apk ready to be deployed on Play Store.

Now I would like to switch to AAB or export my apps as AAB as that is the future of android apps (especially with Google having a deadline of 1st August 2021), but how will I edit the AAB file and add the extra contents in the assets folder the same way I could do with apk in apk editor studio? Is there anything like AAB Editor Studio somewhere even with a different name?

I’ve searched the community and all over the internet with no luck, or perhaps it’s there with some name that I couldn’t think of.

Please help, thanks.